# Table actions with async callbacks

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

**Description**

I have created a table component (`MyTable`), and have set up a column in the table named "Actions"
which can do different actions (such as delete, edit,..) on each row.

Each table action has some properties: icon, text and a callback function (`callbackFn`);

In the `MyTable` code, I want to show a spinner when clicking on an action button by setting: `this.inProgress = true`.

And after the callbackFn is done executing, I need to set `this.inProgress = false`;

The `callbackFn` can be a async api call like the following code:

### myapp.component.ts

```
const tableActions: MyTableActions[] = [

    {
       icon: 'some icon',
       callbackFn: () => {
           http.post<any>('some api').subscribe(r => {
               // IMPORTANT: I need to do some stuff here <========================
               // Note that the code that is here cannot be in the subscribe of the 
               // onActionClick() in the MyTable component.
               // for example I can show a snackbar here and in my second instance
               // of table I show some other messages in UI.
               // However after this finishes, the code in the Table OnActionClick 
               // should always set the inProgress to false, AFTER the stuff in   
               // here is done!
            });
        }
    },
    {
       icon: 'some other icon',
       callbackFn: () => { 
           // some other callback function that does something else (some other action on the row)
    }
];


const someOtherTableActions: MyTablActions[] = [{/*...*/}, {/*...*/}];
```

### myapp.component.html

```
<my-table [actions]="tableActions"><my-table>

<my-table [actions]="someOtherTableActions"><my-table>
```

### my-table.component.ts

```
onActionClick(row) {

    this.inProgress = true;
    callbackFn().subscribe(null, null, () => {
        // on complete, set inProgress to false <==============================

        this.inProgress = false;
    })

}
```

**Problem:**

In the code above I'm subscribing 2 times, so the `http.post gets` called twice.

I read about the .share() but not sure what is a good design on implementing this.

**Question**

So I need to do some action (setting inProgress) after the callbackFn is completed, and the callBackFn itself
does async tasks.

How can we implement this properly?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to subscribe twice, in the first case - you need to return `cold` observable(or just be and `action`) and subscribe only in the component.

in *actions*

```
callback$: http.post<any>('some api')
```

in component:

```
callback$.subscribe(null, null, () => {
    // on complete, set inProgress to false;

    this.inProgress = false;
})
```

or "better" way:

```
callback$.pipe(finalize(() => this.inProgress = false)).subscribe();
```

p.s. adjust if needed, cause I have "developed" here, in StackOverflow answer box :)

Comment: Added some more comments in the code to clarify. This way, first of all the `inProgress` here is not defined. `inProgress` is only defined in the MyTable.Component.ts. This CallBackFn that we initialize here, is used in another class/file/component. and does not have access to the inProgress. Also I should so some other tasks, for example show a snackbar if there is an error.

Comment: callback$ === callbackFn - I named it with $ cause it is obserable(not Fn) and everything is right - `callback$.pipe(finalize(() => this.inProgress = false)).subscribe();` used in my-table.component.ts(you have inProgress there)